# ¿Qué significa el error System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token?

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, xamarin, excepciones

Estoy desarrollando una app en Xamarin.Android en la que tengo que insertarle una firma digital a un PDF.
Cuando llamo a la clase que firma dicho PDF, me da el siguiente error:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000026 (from typeref, class/assembly System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms, System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)

Esta excepción ocurre en la línea 122 del código (`byte[] bytPK = SignMsg(objSHA1.Hash, Certificate, false, Source, TSA);`)

Dejo aquí el código de la clase que uso para firmar a ver si alguien puede encontrar el error, ya que hace un par de días que estoy tratando de solucionarlo y no estoy pudiendo.

```
public static class PDF
{
    /// <param name="Source">Documento origen</param>
    /// <param name="Target">Documento destino</param>
    /// <param name="Certificate">Certificado a utilizar</param>
    /// <param name="Reason">Razón de la firma</param>
    /// <param name="Location">Ubicación</param>
    /// <param name="AddVisibleSign">Establece si hay que agregar la firma visible al documento</param>
    /// FormatPlace. Posibles valores para Lugar de la firma:
    /// A4TL: A4 normal, arriba a la izquierda
    /// A4TR: A4 normal, arriba a la derecha
    /// A4BL: A4 normal, abajo a la izquierda
    /// A4BR: A4 normal, abajo a la derecha
    /// A4aTL: A4 apaisado, arriba a la izquierda
    /// A4aTR: A4 apaisado, arriba a la derecha
    /// A4aBL: A4 apaisado, abajo a la izquierda
    /// A4aBR: A4 apaisado, abajo a la derecha

    public static void SignHashed(string Source, string Target, SysX509.X509Certificate2 Certificate, string Reason, string Location, bool AddVisibleSign, string FormatPlace, string TSA)
    {
        X509CertificateParser objCP = new X509CertificateParser();
        X509Certificate[] objChain = new X509Certificate[] { objCP.ReadCertificate(Certificate.RawData) };

        PdfReader objReader = new PdfReader(Source);
        PdfStamper objStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(objReader, new FileStream(Target, FileMode.Create), '\0');
        PdfSignatureAppearance objSA = objStamper.SignatureAppearance;

        int LastPage = objReader.NumberOfPages;

        if (AddVisibleSign)
        {
            switch (FormatPlace)
            {
                case "A4TL":
                    objSA.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(50, 750, 300, 780), LastPage, null);
                    break;
                case "A4TR":
                    objSA.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(350, 750, 600, 780), LastPage, null);
                    break;
                case "A4BL":
                    objSA.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(50, 50, 300, 80), LastPage, null);
                    break;
                case "A4BR":
                    objSA.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(350, 50, 600, 80), LastPage, null);
                    break;
                case "A4aTL":
                    objSA.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(50, 570, 300, 600), LastPage, null);
                    break;
                case "A4aTR":
                    objSA.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(530, 570, 780, 600), LastPage, null);
                    break;
                case "A4aBL":
                    objSA.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(50, 20, 300, 50), LastPage, null);
                    break;
                case "A4aBR":
                    objSA.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(530, 20, 780, 50), LastPage, null);
                    break;
            }
        }

        objSA.SignDate = DateTime.Now;
        objSA.Certificate = objChain[0];
        objSA.Reason = Reason;
        objSA.Location = Location;
        objSA.Acro6Layers = true;
        objSA.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION;
        PdfSignature objSignature = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKMS, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1);
        objSignature.Date = new PdfDate(objSA.SignDate);
        objSignature.Name = "Test de MQ Emprendimientos";
        if (objSA.Reason != null)
            objSignature.Reason = objSA.Reason;
        if (objSA.Location != null)
            objSignature.Location = objSA.Location;
        objSA.CryptoDictionary = objSignature;
        int intCSize = 4000;
        Hashtable objTable = new Hashtable();
        objTable[PdfName.CONTENTS] = intCSize * 2 + 2;

        var dict = HashtableToDictionary<PdfName, int>(objTable);

        objSA.PreClose(dict);
        
        HashAlgorithm objSHA1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        
        Stream objStream = objSA.GetRangeStream();
        int intRead = 0;
        byte[] bytBuffer = new byte[8192];
        while ((intRead = objStream.Read(bytBuffer, 0, 8192)) > 0)
            objSHA1.TransformBlock(bytBuffer, 0, intRead, bytBuffer, 0);
        objSHA1.TransformFinalBlock(bytBuffer, 0, 0);

        byte[] bytPK = SignMsg(objSHA1.Hash, Certificate, false, Source, TSA);
        byte[] bytOut = new byte[intCSize];

        PdfDictionary objDict = new PdfDictionary();

        Array.Copy(bytPK, 0, bytOut, 0, bytPK.Length);

        objDict.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(bytOut).SetHexWriting(true));
        objSA.Close(objDict);
    }

    public static Dictionary<K, V> HashtableToDictionary<K, V>(Hashtable table)
    {
        return table
          .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
          .ToDictionary(kvp => (K)kvp.Key, kvp => (V)kvp.Value);
    }

    private static byte[] SignMsg(byte[] Message, SysX509.X509Certificate2 SignerCertificate, bool Detached, string Source, string TSA)
    {
        //Creamos el contenedor
        ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(Message);

        //Instanciamos el objeto SignedCms con el contenedor
        SignedCms objSignedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, Detached);

        //Creamos el "firmante"
        CmsSigner objCmsSigner = new CmsSigner(SignerCertificate);

        objCmsSigner.IncludeOption = SysX509.X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly;

        //  Sign the CMS/PKCS #7 message. The second argument is
        //  needed to ask for the pin.
        objSignedCms.ComputeSignature(objCmsSigner, false);

        //Encodeamos el mensaje CMS/PKCS #7
        return objSignedCms.Encode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sería bueno si pudieras ponernos la `InnerException` que te da. De todas maneras, [aqui](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/83410/could-not-resolve-type-with-token-01000012) se exponen varias posibles causas, entre ellas no tener actualizados todos los componentes de xamarin

Comment: Lo que tuve que hacer fue actualizar la dll de System.Security... la baje del administrador de paquetes NuGet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso el problema fue que yo había importado la `System.Security.dll` por defecto de Visual Studio, lo que hice finalmente fue quitar la referencia a esa `.dll` y bajarla nuevamente desde el paquete de `NuGet`